# Use plain mode to access kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I have a Kafka cluster on OpenShift cloud, a customer outside of cloud send message to Kafka cluster, then we set authentication and authorization for Kafka cluster and topic, ans create an user.

Now from external customer can publish messages to kafka topic via SSL or SASL via port 9094, now app inside OpenShift want to consume messages via port 9092 with plain mode, that means, app inside OpenShift doesn't want to use any authentication or authorization to access that topic, do you think if it is possible?

This is my Kafka cluster listener

```
  kafka:
    authorization:
      type: simple
    listeners:
      external:
        authentication:
          type: tls
        port: 9094
        tls: true
        type: route
      plain:
        port: 9092
        tls: false
        type: internal
```

Comment: How did you define the listeners variable on the brokers?

Comment: And how is this different from your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510182/topicauthorizationexception

Comment: I added the listener as the above, please see it

Comment: Do you get any errors trying to use port 9092?